# How does deploying in different Kubernetes namespaces affect pod-to-pod communication?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, containers, gke-networking

I have been deploying in Kubernetes **Default namespace** and it has been well.
However, i now started deploying in different namespaces ie: Development & Production. So my questions is:

Does deployment in different namespaces of kubernetes affect communication between pods which initially have been communicating according to configured firewalls?

currently, these are my namespaces:

```
trevor@deployment-node:~$ kubectl get namespace
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   43d
development       Active   13s
kube-node-lease   Active   43d
kube-public       Active   43d
kube-system       Active   43d
test              Active   13d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the Pods behind [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).it creates a corresponding DNS entry. This entry is of the form `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`, which means that if a container just uses `<service-name>`, it will resolve to the service which is local to a namespace.

if you want to reach across namespaces, you need to use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

```
<service-name>.<service-namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

Normally, you just need the Service’s name and DNS will automatically resolve to the full address. However, if you need to access a Service in another Namespace just use the Service name plus the Namespace name.

For example, if you want to connect to the `database` service in the `test` namespace, you can use the following address:

```
database.test
```

Ref:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#namespaces-and-dns
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-organizing-with-namespaces